# restTemplate.postForObject not sending all the member variables of object

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I am trying to post the object to another service using restTemplate.postForObject, but one of the member variable value is going as 0. But when I try to use rest clients in the chrome browser to send the same post request, then all values are going. Please help me where I am doing wrong.

**Client code**

```
// Sender. Sending the seed object to bidServiceEndpoint + "seedbid".
    private Bid saveSeedBid(Seed seed) {
        Bid bid = new Bid();
        bid.setEmail(seed.getEmail());
        log.info("seed price = " + seed.getSeed_price());
        bid.setNew_price(seed.getSeed_price());
        bid.setSid(seed.getSid());
        log.info("seed info " + seed.toString());
        log.info("Saving seed bid " + bid.toString());
        return restTemplate.postForObject(bidServiceEndpoint + "seedbid", seed, Bid.class);
```

This is printing

```
2021-04-08 21:08:50.168  INFO 13912 --- [nio-5003-exec-7] murali.bidder.seed.service.SeedService   : Saving seed bid Bid(bid=null, bid_time=null, email=xyz@gmail.com, old_price=0, new_price=500, sid=41ee3f6e-0afd-4d26-b827-12e5687fadc2)
```

Observe above that I am passing email, new_price and sid. here new_price value is 500.

**Now here is the server code:-**

```
    @PostMapping("/seedbid")
    public Bid saveSeedBid(@RequestBody Bid bid) {
        log.info("Saving seed bid " + bid.toString());
        return bidService.saveSeedBid(bid);
    }
```

This is printing

```
2021-04-08 21:08:50.189  INFO 13040 --- [nio-5004-exec-1] m.bidder.bid.controller.BidController    : Saving seed bid Bid(bid=null, bid_time=null, email=xyz@gmail.com, old_price=0, new_price=0, sid=41ee3f6e-0afd-4d26-b827-12e5687fadc2)
```

Here if you observe email and sid are coming properly but new_price is coming as 0.

Please help why new_price is coming as zero.

Here is the Bid pojo

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Bid {

    private String bid;
    
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Date bid_time;
    
    private String email;
    
    private int old_price;
    
    private int new_price;
    
    private String sid;
}
```

Comment: Take care of Java Naming conventions. Do not use `_` in variable names. In java it is common sence to use camelCase

Comment: You are sure `seed.getSeed_price()` returns a value differnt from 0?

Comment: Try wrapping the Bid inside a `HttpEntity` and use that `HttpEntity` in `postForObject`.

Comment: Sure. thanks. I will change to use naming conventions. After setting, I am printing log.info("Saving seed bid " + bid.toString()); This output I pasted above 2021-04-08 21:08:50.168  INFO 13912 --- [nio-5003-exec-7] murali.bidder.seed.service.SeedService   : Saving seed bid Bid(bid=null, bid_time=null, email=xyz@gmail.com, old_price=0, new_price=500, sid=41ee3f6e-0afd-4d26-b827-12e5687fadc2)
Here new_price value is 500

Comment: 2021-04-08 21:08:50.167  INFO 13912 --- [nio-5003-exec-7] murali.bidder.seed.service.SeedService   : seed price = 500

Answer (score 0):

I figured.. Sorry. It is small mistake. In client code I am sending seed object which is of type Seed and on the server side I am expecting bid object of type Bid. I should pass the bid object instead of seed object.